# Is 'worked on' right for the sentence?

Tags: prepositions, phrases

I'm a student from Korea and now I'm working at a kind of a language institute. There's an english program going on now and I'm working as a TA there.
Anyway, I have to write a daily log everyday in English. Today I transcribed written survey into an Excel file. In this case, can I write 'I worked on the survey paper' on the log? Is it the right expression?
Help me please and any comments for mistakes in grammar in my question  above are  always welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think you can

> work *on* a topic. Which means to participate or to work towards finishing something (which is your case).

but also

> work *[space]* something.

For example, *work the answers* from your students for a survey. This means using something until there is nothing left. Just like you are *working wood* until it is a table.